# JAGS: error when trying to compare models with different prior distributions

Tags: r, jags

Using this data in R:

```
misprints <- list(N=6, x = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3))
```

I wrote a very simple model with a gamma prior and a Poisson likelihood that looks like this:

```
model {

  # likelihood: poisson
    for(i in 1:N) {
      x[i] ~ dpois(lambda)
  }

  # prior: gamma
  lambda ~ dgamma(9,6)
}
```

I then ran the following code and it seemed to work, (though it didn't perfectly match the mean and variance of prior/posterior distribution that I did by hand):

```
jmodel <- jags.model(file = "misprints1.model", data = misprints)
samps <- jags.samples(jmodel, "lambda", n.iter=1e5)

plot(density(samps$lambda))
```

Next, I attempted to write another script which allowed for compariosn of 3 different priors:

```
data { # create 3 identical data sets for different priors
  for (k in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
      for (i in 1:N) {
        x2[i,j,k] <- x[i]
      }
    }
  }
}


model {
  # likelihood
  for (k in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
      for (i in 1:N) {
        x2[i,j,k] ~ dpois(lambda) 
      }
    }
  }

  # priors
    lambda[1] ~ dgamma(9, 6)
    lambda[2] ~ dunif(0, 10)
    lambda[3] ~ lambda[2] ~ dgamma(0.5, 0.001) # Jeffreys prior
}
```

However, when I run the following:

```
jmodel2 <- jags.model(file = "misprints2.model", data = misprints)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in jags.model(file = "misprints2.model", data = misprints) : 
Error parsing model file:
syntax error on line 25 near "lambda"
```

This error seems to refer to the line beginning:

```
lambda[3] ~ lambda[2] ~ dgamma(0.5, 0.001) # Jeffreys prior
```

I am at a loss for what exactly is going wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly identified that the following line is the problem:

```
lambda[3] ~ lambda[2] ~ dgamma(0.5, 0.001)
```

It is not possible to have 2 relationships (~) or assignments (<-) on the same line.  Neither is it possible to give lambda[2] another relationship, as it has already been defined as dunif(0,10) on the line above.  But the following line should work fine:

```
lambda[3] ~ dgamma(0.5, 0.001)
```

I can't see why this line referenced lambda[2] in your code unless you were trying to define lambda[3] as a function of lambda[2]?

--- EDIT ---

Complete functioning R & JAGS code below:

```
library('runjags')

model <- '
data { # create 3 identical data sets for different priors
  for (k in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
      for (i in 1:N) {
        x2[i,j,k] <- x[i]
      }
    }
  }
}


model {
  # likelihood
  for (k in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
      for (i in 1:N) {
        x2[i,j,k] ~ dpois(lambda[k]) 
      }
    }
  }

  # priors
    lambda[1] ~ dgamma(9, 6)
    lambda[2] ~ dunif(0, 10)
    lambda[3] ~ dgamma(0.5, 0.001) # Jeffreys prior
}
#data# N, x
#monitor# lambda
'

N <- 6
x <- c(3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3)
run.jags(model)
```

Comment: Ah, a silly error in my code! But even when I remove the reference to lambda[2], I get this:

Error in jags.model(file = "misprints2.model", data = misprints) : 
  Error in node lambda
Invalid vector parameter in distribution dpois

Comment: x2[i,j,k] ~ dpois(lambda) should be x2[i,j,k] ~ dpois(lambda[k])

Comment: Taking that change on, I now get:

Error in jags.model(file = "misprints2.model", data = misprints) : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 17.
Index out of range taking subset of  lambda

Comment: I tried what I suggested and got no error. See the complete code example now in my answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right--I had put in lambda[i] rather than lambda[k]. It works perfectly now--thanks!